# How to use JavaScript in PHP save as function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, save-as

I am new in PHP. I have a form which have different submit button Like Save, Edit, Cancel and Save as. Now i want when user click on Save as button java script is run and Check the file name. If there is a already exists file with same name in db then display a alert message "Please Change file name" if user change file name then execute the code of button.
 I use code for buttons

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save as" onclick="show_confirm()" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Make a copy" />
```

and in PhP

```
if($_POST['submit'] == 'Make a copy') {
        $action = "copy";
    } elseif($_POST['submit'] == 'Save as') {
        $action = "save as";
    }
```

and may be java script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_confirm()
        {
            var r=confirm("Please Change File Name!?");
            if (r==true)
            {                   
            }
            else
            {                    
            }
        } 
</script>
```

my form look like this
[image: save as]

Now i am trying to write my Java Script for alert message can u please help me to sort out my problem?

Comment: Do not do it this way, instead, when user chooses a file for upload, send an AJAX request to server and check if there is already a file then ask for use to perform diff action

Comment: we can't use same submit button name twice :)

Comment: @Elangovan oh sure we can

Comment: @Umair there is no file upload option on my form

Comment: there is no file upload option on my form ` so what are your trying to upload/save or replace? :P

Comment: @Elangovan we can do it i just show in my PHP code how we use SUBMIT Twice

Comment: @ Umair i am trying that when user click on Edit button then it is able to save same data with different file name

Comment: @michal <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save as" onclick="show_confirm()" />
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Make a copy" />

Comment: @Umair i Update my question with Image of my form

Comment: Dont name the buttons the same btw, php won't like that when you check for a submit. It won't know which one you pressed. And start with an `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` and then your submit statement, else you make php code run unneccesairy

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want some AJAX to run when you click "Save as" to poll the server for an existing file name. If such a file name exists, then display an alert message. Is this correct?

Comment: @Drakes yes i exactly want this

Comment: May I ask, what name should it check for, How do you determine the name to seek? Or can only be 1 file uploaded at the time?

Comment: @Dorvalla look at image of my form. There is no file upload option. It is a form which store data in database and after that i fetch that data in PDF format. And here file name is actually the name of file of PDF

Comment: Yes, I get that sunny, but how do you determine what information it should be picked up. You check by id, or by name, that was what i meant?

Comment: @Dorvalla i have done my work with some other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="program.php" method="post">
    Default value in this case: Maurize
    <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="Username"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save as"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Make a copy" />
</form>
```

now you can check names:

```
<?php
$oldUsername = "Maurize"; //Will be triggered out of database

$newUsername = $_POST["filename"]; //This is from html
switch ($_POST['submit']) {
    case 'Save as':
        if ($oldUsername == $newUsername){ //If the name is already present
            echo('<script>alert("Please change your filename because it already exists"); window.location.href = "index.html";</script>');
        }
        else{
            echo('<script>alert("Creating your filename was succesfully"); window.location.href = "index.html";</script>');
        }
    break;
    case 'Make a copy':
        echo "make a copy";
    break;
}
?>
```

Now we have our standart form at top. If we submit this our program.php gets called like below. If the name is already present we alert him and send him back to page.

Comment: Maurize i want something different. I want to display alert message on save as button after checking file name

Comment: You have to check filename in php with your value in database first. If this check gives out true for example you can trigger the javascript. Give me a moment.

Comment: try this. was the fastest solution I got.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82164/discussion-between-sunny-and-maurize).

Answer (score 1):

instead of submit button with same name, use these

```
<input type="button"  value="Save as" onclick="show_confirm(1)" />
<input type="button" value="Make a copy"  onclick="show_confirm(2)" />
<input type="hidden" value="" id="what_to_do" name="what_to_do" />
enter code here
```

and in your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_confirm(a)
    {

        if (a == 1) {

            $("#what_to_do").val("save_as");
        }
        if (a == 2) {

            $("#what_to_do").val("make_copy");
        }

        // now submit form
        $('#myForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

And in you PHP side

```
<?php

 // $_POST['what_to_do'] is actually this one -  <input type="hidden" value="" id="what_to_do" name="what_to_do" />
if ($_POST['what_to_do'] == 'make_copy') {
    $action = "copy";
} elseif ($_POST['what_to_do'] == 'save_as') {
    $action = "edit";
}
```

Comment: Where is alert message? how this script check the file name?

Comment: and he uses jquery, so be sure you have it linked in head. check my code for better solution.

Comment: @sunny which field is the file name?

Comment: @Umair look on my form first field is File name